# IPv6 routing on Linux

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6

We have a problem with a simple IPv6 routing setup. People have asked the question before but none of the suggested answers seem to fit our case.

We have a network spanning hundreds of IPv4 VPN connected nodes and we would like to extend them concurrently with IPv6. For that purpose we test on 3 hosts running Linux 5.10 LTS with randomly chosen and manually assigned ULA's (IP's below are also randomly generated in the same way):

Host A:

```
eth0 fd68:8fdd:bb68::2/64
(route fd3d:7eec:51a3::/64 via fd68:8fdd:bb68::1)
```

Host B:

```
eth0 fd68:8fdd:bb68::1/64
eth1 fd3d:7eec:51a3::1/64
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1<
ip6tables FORWARD set to ACCEPT
```

Host C:

```
eth0 fd3d:7eec:51a3::2/64
(route fd68:8fdd:bb68::/64 via fd3d:7eec:51a3::1)
```

Ping A->B and C->B works.
Ping B->A and B->C works.
Ping A->C and C->A exibits the same analogous behaviour (as shown by debugging on B):

```
$ tcpdump -i eth0 -l ip6
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:05:12.943486 IP6 fd68:8fdd:bb68::2 > fd3d:7eec:51a3::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 0, length 64
13:05:13.936869 IP6 fd68:8fdd:bb68::2 > fd3d:7eec:51a3::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
13:05:14.945670 IP6 fd68:8fdd:bb68::2 > fd3d:7eec:51a3::2: ICMP6, echo request, seq 2, length 64
(continues..)

$ tcpdump -i eth1 -l ip6
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
(nothing..)

$ ip6tables -L -v | grep FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
```

I believe something very simple is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348533/is-net-ipv6-conf-all-forwarding-1-equivalent-to-enabling-forwarding-for-all-indi), you need to set `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` rather than (or in addition to) setting the flag on individual interfaces, which is used for controlling router behaviour more granularly.